# Apache mod_jk LB synchronization server startup + application startup time

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, high-availability, jboss, ajp

after a long search I can´t found a solution or path to solve my problem with synchronization startup of Apache and Backend servers.

I have a Apache2 using a LoadBalancer with mod_jk that balance request to 4 backend servers using JBoss and AJP protocol. So all configuration works very well but I have a small issue with synchronization between Apache and startup time of applications in JBoss.

JBoss is started and accept connections in AJP port before startup of your applications complete yet, so when JBoss node is already used in Apache LB the application not yet available and I have a time of failure requests when JBoss is starting or when I need to replace version of application. I know that is possible to remove node from LB and after all ok with node I can return the same to LB, so my question is if is it possible use of URL Check or configure JBoss to only listen AJP port after all applications are deployed or other option that I don´t need to directly remove node from LB when the same is starting or in the case that JBoss server is not down but only application is down ?

I saw the parameter fail_on_status in JK, is it the only option in this case ?

Any experience will be very appreciated.
Thanks